# closure requires unique access to `self` but it is already borrowed

Tags: rust

I basically have the following code that needs to modify a vector field (by removing some items through the `retains` function) and in the predicate of that `retains` function, I need to call a mutable function on self :

```
struct Task {}

struct Processor {
    counter: u32,
    tasks: Vec<Task>
}

impl Processor {
    
    fn execute(&mut self, task: &Task) -> bool {
        self.counter += 1;
        // Do some stuff with task and return wether it was sucessfully executed
        true
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        self.tasks.retain(|task| !self.execute(task))
    }
}
```

The compiler complains with two errors:

```
error[E0501]: cannot borrow `self.tasks` as mutable because previous closure requires unique access
  --> src/main.rs:90:9
   |
90 |         self.tasks.retain(|task| !self.execute(task))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^------^------^^----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |          |      |       |
   |         |          |      |       first borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
   |         |          |      closure construction occurs here
   |         |          first borrow later used by call
   |         second borrow occurs here

error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `self` but it is already borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:90:27
   |
90 |         self.tasks.retain(|task| !self.execute(task))
   |         ---------- ------ ^^^^^^  ---- second borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
   |         |          |      |
   |         |          |      closure construction occurs here
   |         |          first borrow later used by call
   |         borrow occurs here
```

I do understand the issue, but how do I make this work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust doesn't yet have a way of only borrowing certain members of `self`. Because of this, it can't infer that you aren't mutating both `self.tasks` and `self.counter` at the same time. All it knows is that you're trying to mutate `self` twice at the same time.

To work around this, you'll need to move `tasks` out of `self`, then perform the operation you want, then move it back into `self`.

Rust has a handy operation that does exactly this in the standard library. Since `Vec` implements `Default` (yielding an empty vector, no allocation necessary), we can use [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```
    fn run(&mut self) {
        // swaps `self.tasks` with an empty `Vec`, and yields `tasks` to us
        // this won't allocate, because `Vec::new` and therefore `Vec::default` do not
        let mut tasks = std::mem::take(&mut self.tasks);
        // do what we want with it
        tasks.retain(|task| !self.execute(task));
        // move it back into `self`
        self.tasks = tasks;
    }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ab232c6f0479410ed578e5cf747f872)

Comment: I see. That's clever. I understand why this would work. As you pointed out correctly, in the mutable function I am not mutating tasks, but rust doesn't know about this and asumes that tasks could be modified. Had thought about splitting up the struct in two parts, but this solution is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: FWIW the first paragraph isn't entirely true: [Rust does support partial borrow when doing direct field accesses](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d454d4890da4398570d5bdb99e3264ef), Rust doesn't (and can't, really, it would leak implementation details) support partial borrows "through" function calls, a function call necessarily borrows the entire object (and conflicts with any extant partial borrow).

Comment: Note however that if the "some stuff" the OP does inside `execute` attempts to queue a new task for later execution, then that queued task will be lost when `task` is moved back.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Split your struct into the right parts so they can be borrowed separately. The key part here is that `execute` doesn't take `&mut Processor`, only `&mut Engine`.

```rust
struct Task {}

struct Engine {
    counter: u32,
}

struct Processor {
    engine: Engine,
    tasks: Vec<Task>
}

impl Engine {
    fn execute(&mut self, task: &Task) -> bool {
        self.counter += 1;
        true
    }
}

impl Processor {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let engine = &mut self.engine;
        self.tasks.retain(|task| !engine.execute(task))
    }
}
```

---

Option 2: Move the tasks vector out with [std::mem::take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html), so they're temporarily owned by the function instead of the `Processor`, then put them back:

```rust
impl Processor {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let mut tasks = std::mem::take(&mut self.tasks);
        tasks.retain(|task| !self.execute(task));
        self.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

(This does not copy the memory for all the tasks, because the `Vec`'s heap allocated storage is undisturbed by moving the `Vec` value itself.)

---

Option 3: If in a more complex situation you can't find a split between parts or a temporary move that works for all your operations, then you could use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to do run-time instead of compile-time borrow checking — you'd need one cell for `tasks` and another cell or cells for the parts `execute` needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought as well that option 1 would work, but it seems to give similar compilation errors. Option 2 works though.

Comment: @quentinadam Whoops, that's because the *closure* borrows `self`. I'll fix that...there. I checked that it compiles now.

Comment: I see, thanks for that ! Option 1 works now and it's very insightful to see both options here.